# is(':first') returns different (wrong?) results for what should be the same element. jsFiddle inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/garnwraly/sfrwU/2/

given HTML of only

```
<li>
    <button id="bam">click</button>
</li>
```

and this script

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
    //console.log( e.currentTarget == $('button')[0] ); //true;
    //console.log($('li').is('li:first')); //true

    console.log($(e.currentTarget).parent().is('li:first')) //false
    console.log($('button').parent().is('li:first')); //true
    console.log($($('button')[0]).parent().is('li:first')); //false
});
```

why is `$(e.currentTarget).parent().is('li:first')` false?

Comment: It could be bubbling up the DOM - when you click on a child element the click bubbles up to its parent elements.

Comment: @jqueryrocks that's not what's happening here; it has something to do with the semantics of `:first`

Comment: `$(e.currentTarget)[0]==$('button')[0]` is `true`, so I don't know how this is possible. Very strange.

Comment: I'm starting to lean towards the answer that yes, this is a jQuery bug.

Comment: @robertc I'm getting `false` from Firefox. *edit* - same from Chrome.

Comment: @Pointy Never mind, the fiddle had different code, didn't check

Comment: @undefined and @robertc thanks, I'm getting three 'true's from your fiddles as well and that would indeed solve my problem. The main difference seems to be that you are passing in a jQuery object to the `is` function, which works, and the code that doesn't work correctly (even though it should) is passing in a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After step debugging through the jQuery code as this ran, this turns out to be an issue with the way the `jQuery()` method is used within the `is()` method. As we know, [you can pass a context into the method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context), and internally, this context is being used with the `is()` method (and is being set differently for the various selectors).

When `$(e.currentTarget)` is used, the context is set to the button that triggered the event. While when `$('button')` is used, the context is set to the `Document` object. This makes sense when you think of how these selectors need to be scoped.

Here is the relevant part of the `is()` method:

```
jQuery( selector, this.context ).index( this[0] ) >= 0
```

Based on that, when run as $(e.currentTarget), the call to the `jQuery()` method is evaluation to:

```
jQuery("li:first", "button#bam").index( this[0] ) >= 0
```

Which is obviously returning -1, and reporting as `false`

Comment: Confirmed! Using `$(e.currentTarget).parent().is.call(document, 'li:first')` works correctly. Updated fiddle with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/garnwraly/sfrwU/29/

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be that `:first` only cares about *matching* - in the case that the jQuery object is constructed from a DOM element, there's no selector matching going on. Note that

```
console.log($(document.getElementById('bam')).is(':first'));
```

also logs `false`.

I don't feel that the behavior is correct, and a bug should probably be logged, but even if it worked properly I don't think that in this case testing `:first` really does any good. If you use `.parent()` to navigate up the DOM to the parent node starting from a single element, then it's pointless to ask whether the parent is the first element - there'll always be a parent (except from the DOM root of course), and always just one.

If you do it with `:first-child`, which would actually be interesting but not necessarily relevant, then it works as one might expect because `:first-child` is actually about the structure of the DOM. The `:first` qualifier is just about being the first matched element.

Comment: Thanks Pointy!
I do think I have a legitimate use for the `:first` selector though, the code in my original fiddle was reduced to be just enough to reproduce the error
I have a container with structure of 

    ...
    <div>
        <div class="apple">not important what's in here</div>
        <div class="orange"><button/></div>
        <div class="orange"><button/></div>
    </div>

and I want to have a slightly different behavior for when a button belonging to the first `div.orange` is clicked.

Comment: Sorry forgot can't format comments. Here's a fiddle showing why `:first-child` wouldn't work for me for my use case  
http://jsfiddle.net/garnwraly/sfrwU/25/

Comment: @CheapSteaks well checking `$(whatever).index() === 0` should be the same, conceptually, as checking `.is(':first')`.